# Stuck on a step in Gauss' proof of the Normal Distribution

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm reading through Gauss' proof (with small modifications) as it appears [in this article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/stahl96.pdf). I'm stuck at this step (bottom of page 105 (text) 10 (pdf)):

\begin{equation*}
  0 = \frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial\bar{M}} = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
  -\phi'(M_1-\bar{M})\phi(M_2-\bar{M})\cdots\phi(M_n-\bar{M})
  \label{none}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
  -\phi(M_1-\bar{M})\phi'(M_2-\bar{M})\cdots\phi(M_n-\bar{M})
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  -\cdots
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  -\phi(M_1-\bar{M})\phi(M_2-\bar{M})\cdots\phi'(M_n-\bar{M})
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  =-\left( \frac{\phi'(M_1-\bar{M})}{\phi(M_1-\bar{M})} + \frac{\phi'(M_2-\bar{M})}{\phi(M_2-\bar{M})} + \cdots + \frac{\phi'(M_n-\bar{M})}{\phi(M_n-\bar{M})} \right)\Omega
\end{equation*}

Here $\Omega$ is the joint distribution, $\phi$ is the unknown (eventually shown to be the Normal Distribution), and $\bar{M}$ the mean and therefore the term that maximizes the joint distribution. From what I can tell to get to the last step we must have:

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{\phi(M_1-\bar{M})} =\phi(M_2-\bar{M})\phi(M_3-\bar{M})\cdots\phi(M_n-\bar{M}) 
\end{equation*}

But I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to consider the factor  $Ω$ at the end, so that really
$$
\fracΩ{ϕ(M_1−\bar M)}=ϕ(M_2-\bar M)ϕ(M_3−\bar M)⋯ϕ(M_n−\bar M)
$$
as was the construction from the beginning.

---

In general, logarithmic differentiation of $f(x)=f_1(x)⋯f_n(x)$ will lead to
$$
\ln|f(x)|=\ln|f_1(x)| +…+\ln|f_n(x)|
\\
\implies
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f_1'(x)}{f_1(x)} +…+\frac{f_n'(x)}{f_n(x)}
$$

Comment: I understand both of your points but I do not see how they fit together in the context of this proof.

Comment: The first point corrects what you wrote down, second point is an alternative way to arrive at the derivatives formula.

Comment: I think the notation of last line of the proof is what is confusing me. Is he saying that stuff times the joint distribution? That being the case your correction then elucidates the proof.